# Inserting time into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, insert

Example query:

```
INSERT INTO Table
VALUES (CAST('13-07-2001' AS DATE))
```

Ends with

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Swapping month with day fixes the issue, but i would prefer using global system, not American.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you can find that the style of your dates is `105`.
So you can do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table
VALUES (CONVERT(DATE, '13-07-2001', 105))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a standard format.  For SQL Server, YYYYMMDD always works for dates:

```
INSERT INTO Table (datecol)
    VALUES (CAST('20010713' AS DATE))
```

You should list the columns that you are inserting into, as well.